# Coupled oscillators - why is the order of $x_2 - x_1$ or vice versa the way it is?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, coupled-oscillators

In my physics class, we have been working on the two mass, three spring (coupled oscillator) problem and I found this great video that helps explain how to set up one of these problems. (Link: [Coupled oscillator video at time 7:00](https://youtu.be/-pXnfzQfupE)) However, I don’t understand why we take the order of change in $x$ such that it is the position associated with that mass minus the position associated with the other mass...for example, what is we were looking at mass 1 but mass 2 was much heavier or a Spring not directly connected was much stronger?

[image: Screenshot of point in video referenced in question]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. A diagram and/or some equations might explain better than words. Also if you refer to a video, you need to provide a time-mark to direct other users to the part which you are referring to.

Comment: @sammygerbil Absolutely! I added a screenshot of the point in the video that I was referring to, and it’s also at 7:03! Sorry for any confusion. It’s probably a question with an obvious answer but I just don’t want to have to memorize an equation if there’s a simple physical explanation.

Comment: In the 1st line try writing the force on the left mass as $+K(x_2-x_1)$. This is in the direction $+x_1$.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thank you so much! That helps a lot. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don’t understand why we take the order of change in x such that it is the position associated with that mass minus the position associated with the other mass

Because the stretch of the middle spring depends on the position of both masses, and we defined both $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be positive if the masses move to the right.

> what is we were looking at mass 1 but mass 2 was much heavier

Then the l.h.s.'s of the two equations would be $m_1\ddot{x}_1$ and $m_2\ddot{x}_2$ instead of both using the same mass.

> or a Spring not directly connected was much stronger?

You have to solve the complete system of equations to find how a not-directly-connected spring affects each mass. (Actually true in the presented case as well as if you assumed unequal spring constants, but if the problem isn't symmetrical of course you'll get different amplitudes of displacement and velocity for each mass)

*Edit*

In comments you asked,

> is the defining rightward motion as positive a convention or a requirement?

In principle it's an arbitrary choice. In practice, most people seem to choose to have a position variable increase as an object moves to the right (and draw their x-y graphs with positive x to the right, etc).

In your problem this choice was clearly communicated in the diagram showing the mechanical setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So is the defining rightward motion as positive a convention or a requirement?